# Angular passing Json to google spreadsheet getPost throws e = undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, google-apps-script

Hy Guys, first question by the way, I am trying to insert form data with Angular $http funtion into a Google spreadsheet using an appscript made by mhawksey/gist:1276293.

What is the problem: all post request I do ending up as undifiend entries inside my spreadsheet, thus the e parameter inside the getPost(e) function doesn´t get any arguments. I really dont know where the breaking point is because the get response from my google spreadsheets send all object data.

thank you all in advance!

### index.php

```
<html ng-app="ngApp"> 
        <head>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

        </head>

        <body ng-controller="controller">
         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>


     <div id="test">
         <form name="form" ng-submit="submit()">
             <label>NAME</label>
            <input type="text" name="Name" ng-model="user.name">            
            {{user.name}}
             <label>SURNAME</label>
         <input type="text" name="Surname" ng-model="user.surname">            
            {{user.surname}}
         <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>     
             </form>
                </div>


         <script src="app.js"></script>

        </body>

    </html>
```

### app.js

```
var ngApp = angular.module('ngApp', []);
ngApp.controller('controller', function($scope, $http) {

$scope.user={};



$scope.submit=function() {

    $http({
          method  : 'POST',
          url     : "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbz2-BH3gDv_Wkjpg39vBwGvpUVbcBDNOHmtXfk9lRUoT04mRPw/exec",
          data    : $scope.user, //forms user object
          headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} 
         })
     .then(function successCallback(response, statusText,data,config) {
    console.log("succees");
    console.log(statusText);
    console.log(data);
    console.log(config);
    console.log($scope.user.name);
        // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function errorCallback(response, statusText,data,config) {

        console.log(statusText);
    console.log("failed");
        console.log(data);
    console.log(config);
    console.log($scope.user.name);// called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });





};

});
```

Comment: You will have to make a page redirection because XHR requests to the Google Apps Script server are forbidden, so here you might be getting an error and if you want to see the error then add the error function for the response.

Comment: Thx for your advice, but all i get ist one Post with 200 and one get with 304, i do not recive any 302 responses, i kinda new to  this field, so please bear with me :)

Answer (score 0):

You should handle errors in the error function of the $http.

```
$http({...}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

So maybe it's deliviering an error, so you get no filled data.

Comment: Hy, thx for your reply, I tried to edit it, so I can get some information. When I submit my form, the sucesscallback function gets called and gives me :console.log(statusText) = undifiend       console.log(data); = undfiend

Comment: Because your actual 'data' is 'response'. Try console.log(response) inside your successCallback. This should be the data, if the $http-call is returning anything.

Comment: This yields [object object]

Comment: only console.log(data) and not something like console.log('data': + data)